# opencv : set model position using rotation and translation vector

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a 3D model in unity. I calculate rotation and translation vector using opencv solvePnP vector.

Now, I try to set model position with these values. My C# code is below :

```
Vector3 objPosition;
objPosition.x = gameObject.transform.position.x + tvec.x;
objPosition.y = gameObject.transform.position.y + tvec.y; 
objPosition.z = gameObject.transform.position.z + tvec.z;
gameObject.transform.position = objPosition;

Quaternion quat = new Quaternion(rvec.x, rvec.y, rvec.z, 1.0f);
gameObject.transform.rotation = quat;
```

But the result is not true for me. How can I use opencv rotation and translation vector in unity?

**EDIT**

I have a 3d model. I determine correspondencs point on object and model manually.I want to put on 2d image that contains a known object. I get camera and object relation using `solvePnp`.

I use, to show 3d model on unity scene, opencv rotation and translation vector. Maybe I should change my question.

How can I detect object position and orientation using 3d-2d point correspondences?

Comment: What kind of values solvePnP returns and kind of what values are you expecting? For translation maybe issues with scale/units?

Comment: openCV rotation vector from solvePnP isn't quaternion but a rodrigues rotation. Does unity allow you to specify rotations by rodrigues formula or matrix notation? Otherwise you'll have to transform the rodrigues rotation to a qutaternion. I don't know how to do that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternions for differences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rodrigues_parameters_and_Gibbs_representation

Comment: @Micka wiki says that qi^2 + qj^2 + qk^2 + qr^2 = 1(x,y,z,w for quaternion). Because I know x,y,z, I calculate w. But result is not expected for me. Object position is not true.

Comment: no, the `(x,y,z)` that you have from solvePnP are RODRIGUES rotation x,y,z (or better said kx, ky, kz) and not quaternions

Comment: Thanks @Micka. these wikipedia links are very useful.

Comment: @zumma that's nice to hear. I hope you'll find a way to transform from rodrigues to quaternion. If however you can use 4x4 transformation matrices in unity (instead of quaternion or euler angles) you can use the openCV function `cv::Rodrigues` : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20Rodrigues%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20jacobian%29 and extend the result to a 4x4 extended coordinate matrix by adding a 4th `0 0 0 1` row and a `tx ty tz 1` column. But I didn't test, hope this isn't wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the  [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) for Euler to Quaternion calculations

```
Quaternion quat = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(rvec.x, rvec.y, rvec.z))
```

Comment: quat values are 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 for 1.163, 0.946,-1.435(x-y-x).